# android bug or a misuse of Configuration object?

Tags: android, configuration, locale

We have a bit of code in the Application object onCreate method that changes the default local in the configuration of the ApplicationContext.

it looks something like:

```
Locale locale = new Locale(sSavedLocale);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Than we start our main activity and from there our other activities and tasks.
As long as i don't cause configuration change like screen rotation everything is ok.
if i rotate the screen the Locale returns to the device default, even though the application object remains the same.

Digging into android srouce code of ActivityThread and other inner classes i could see the the ApplicationContext itself and the context in the mainThread is changed back to default on configuration change event.

It seems like a bug to me since i i set the configuration in the application level at app start i probably want to maintain the change unless Local configuration change occurred, and even then....

I didn't check for open bugs i do think of applying one.
Anyone thinks i'm wrong and this is ok behavior ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `onConfigurationChanged` to your `Application` class.

```
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (newConfig.locale != null)
        {
            Locale locale = new Locale(sSavedLocale);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
    }
```

Comment: interesting, i'll check and get back to u!
10x!
I still think it's a bug that i change the Configuration of the current context and it doesn't get saved, onConfigurationChanged will be called, as far as i know in any case, so maybe u are right and that's the place to perform the change.

Comment: that method works, i have no idea why, probably application gets the change before the activity so i can centralize the change in one place, it doesn't matter, it works well :-)